# How to display more than 100 as a search result?

Tags: search-results

When doing a search, and getting a result of more than 100, it is not possible to display all at the same page. It is only limited to 25, 50 or 100.

How can I display more than 100 search results on the same page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CiviCRM version 4.5+ you can control exactly how many results are shown per page. At the bottom-right corner of the search results, click the up/down arrows to increment the count by 25, or type in whatever number you wish:

[image: Rows per page]

Comment: Cool! Didn't know that. I am on 4.4.LTS

Comment: Also, if you are using a Listing, you can add "&crmRowCount=N" to the URL and specify the limit of results you want to get back.

Answer (score 2):

If you choose to display 100 as search result, your URL will change. The last number in the URL is setting how many you want to display.

Simply overwrite the number 100 with  the number you desire, and then hit enter.